How to execute a Quarto document in parent directory
By default (i.e., when I click on the "render" button in RStudio), a Quarto document is rendered with its own file location as working directory. Is it possible to execute it using the parent directory as working directory?
This can be achieved by running quarto::quarto_render("reports/my_report.qmd", execute_dir = "absolute_path_to_parent_directory") but this seems tedious compared to clicking the "render" button.
In RMarkdown, there used to be an option what should be used as the working directory and Quarto Projects (which I am not using) have the option execute-dir – which unfortunately does not seem to exist for single documents.
PS: Workarounds involving here::here() are probably not useful in my use case.
